# Mongo multiples databases vs one big collection

Tags: mongodb

Is it better to create one Mongo databases per each user with thousand documents in one collection or one database with millions of documents in one collection?

---

I do not want to exchange data through the users. It will be completely separate.

Comment: *it depends* - a lot more information is required to even be able to attempt to answer this - and as it stands it doesn't look like it's programming related anyway. With a bit more information it may be suitable for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This really depends on your situation, what indexes you plan to use and how you plan to query your data. As it currently stands your question is to broad to be answered in this context.

Comment: This basic question is asked a lot on StackOverflow.

Comment: +1 to @WiredPrairie I have anmswered two of these this week

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most powerful structure to store the information depend by query that you want to perform.
For example, if you want to execute a query between more users should consider the hypothesis of a single private collection.
Mongo db also offers an efficient system for the distribution of the workload across multiple machines in a completely transparent see [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/)

Comment: I think the best solution is a collection for each user because MongoDB defines indexes on a per-collection level.

Comment: Why do you think that? What if there are millions of users? The question did not provide enough details to give a reasonable answer.

Comment: If you are millions of users, you can create one collection for each users but not create 1 database for users. Generally, having large number of collections has no significant performance penalty and results in very good performance. Distinct collections are very important for high-throughput batch processing.

Comment: You would NEVER create 1 collection per user, that would be a terrible idea due to how MongoDB internals work. Also I don't see how sharding supports what you just said about isolation of databases, the case is that you put a db per server manually, sharding is for a sigle database to shard its collections, also how does a index being defined on collection level make it better for 1 user per collection?